# Dynamically change color of enlighten status bar

Tags: python

I would like to have a status bar that dynamically changes color without having to remake the bar every time.

```
import enlighten
manager = enlighten.get_manager()
status_bar = manager.status_bar("Starting",
            color="white_on_blue",
            justify=enlighten.Justify.CENTER,
            autorefresh=True,
        )
status_bar.update("Working", color= "white_on_red")
```

Is there a way of doing this using the update method?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `color` attribute. It does the same validation for the color that's done when you originally set it, but caches it so it doesn't have to do that processing again.

In your example this would look like.

```py
status_bar.color = "white_on_red"
status_bar.update("Working")
```